# Disable paypal express when enabling paypal standard in Magento 1.9.1

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, paypal-express

I am facing some weird issue. I cannot disable PayPal express checkout on my Magento store running on 1.9.1. I have checked in another version of Magento. The only difference I found is the current store has Merchant Country as Thailand where as other have a country as United state. Please guide me to get this issue solved

Comment: what did you tried to disable the payapal?

Comment: I am not getting option to paypal express when I enable PayPal Standard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found answer to the question

```
update core_config_data 
set value = '1' 
where path = 'payment/paypal_standard/active';
```

by this I could enable only paypal standard

Comment: I found the path to be the one below, and not this one.

Comment: You just run this query in sql

Comment: That path doesn't exist, at least not in my instance of 1.9.0.2. The path in the query in the other answer does exist and works.

Answer (score 4):

After configuring Paypal Standard the option to configure Paypal Express becomes disabled:

[image]

Trying running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'payment/paypal_express/active';
```

Are any of the values `1`?  Try changing them to `0` and see if that gets the desired result.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks :) But Is it a proper mean to accomplish this ? There must some reason behind disabling Configure button in the CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, found under the paypal payment settings

> system->configuration->payment_methods->paypal

is the `advanced settings` link for `Express checkout`, under the `Basic Settings-PayPal Express Checkout`.

Set the dropdown `Payment Applicable From` to `Specific Countries`, and then don't select any countries from the `Countries Payment Applicable` selection area. It will effectively disable paypal express and remove the option from the onepage checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

ENABLING PAYMENT STANDARDS

You can easily enable Payment Standards in Magento 1.9 by running the below database query:

update core_config_data set value = 1 where path = 'payment/paypal_standard/active';

DISABLE PAYPAL EXPRESS

update core_config_data set value = 0 where path = 'payment/paypal_express/active';

then it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

There's two options I need to disable to show Paypal Standard without express checkout option under the **System -> Configuration -> Payment Methods -> Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout)**:

```
1) Display on Product Details Page
2) Advanced settings -> Display on Shopping Cart
```

I set both to **No**, flushed the cache and I don't see paypal express on product page, cart and checkout. But Paypal standard is still there on checkout.